# How to handle form input with AJAX GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

This is my first attempt to create a page with HTML and javascript.

I have created a Form with 2 input (form and to date) and submit Button. The same page contains the table.

```
<h1 style="text-align:center"><b style="color:#ccc">ALM Availability Report</b></h1> 
<form id="availform" method="get">
<label for="fromdate"> FROM DATE </label>
<input id="from" type="datetime-local" name="fromdate">
<label for="enddate"> TO DATE </label>
<input id="end" type="datetime-local" name="enddate">
<button name="submit_button" class="submit_button" id="submit_button">Submit</button>
</form>
<br>
<br>
<div id=almserv >
    <span  style="top:10%;">ALM Service Availability %</span><br><br><br>
    <span id=servnum style="top:20%;font-size:75pt;"></span>
</div>
<br>
<br>

<div id="spinner" class="spinner" style="display:none;">
    <img id="img-spinner" src="./images/ajax-loader4.gif" alt="Loading"/>
</div>      

    <table id="service_table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Service Name</th>
                            <th>Service Desc</th>
                            <th>Time OK %</th>
                            <th>Time Warning %</th>
                            <th>Time Critical %</th>
                        </tr
                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                    </table>
```

I'm using Nagios for server monitoring. I have generated the REST API url to access the Nagios and fetch the availability report. I need to pass the from date and to date form input to the AJAX call of the URL.

```
var end =  Form todate
var start = Form fromdate
servicereport = " http://xx.xx.xx/nagios/cgi-bin/archivejson.cgi?query=availability&availabilityobjecttype=servicegroups&hostgroup=ALM&servicegroup=ALM+Tools&assumedinitialhoststate=up&assumedinitialservicestate=ok&starttime=" + start + "&endtime=" + end;
$.support.cors = true;

 $.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: servicereport,
 crossDomain: true,
 beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization',
                        make_base_auth("nagiosadmin", "nagiosadmin"));
                },

 dataType: 'json',     //data format
 success: servicedisplay
 });
```

On success, the table will be updated with the values.

How to achieve this?

Comment: So add a submit handler, cancel the submission, and make the call?

Comment: Could you please share the code snippet.

Comment: `$("#availForm").submit(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); //your ajax code here });` Pretty sure you can google examples of adding a submit event handler via jquery...did you not search for anything? To pass the dates to your endpoint, set the `data` parameter in the ajax request. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this by below javascript.

HTML :

```
<form name="NAME" id="avialform" action="">
  <fieldset>
     <legend style="color:white">AVAILABILITY REPORT</legend>
     <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="vzuui-detailpanel">
        <tr>
           <td><label>From Date :</label><input id="from" type="datetime-local" name="fromdate" /></td>
           <td><label>To Date :</label><input id="to" type="datetime-local" name="todate" /></td>
        </tr>
     </table>
  </fieldset>
   <button class="vzuui-btn-red-active closeedit" type="button" id="getrepo">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#getrepo").click(function(){
var Fdate = document.getElementById("from").value;
var Tdate = document.getElementById("to").value;
//ajax call

});
});
```